# AppIcon does not appear on iPhone 5S iOS 11 with Xcode 9

Tags: iphone, ios10, ios11, xcode9

I have a project with 5 Targets. All of these have their own .xcassets (Assets) that holds LaunchImages, AppIcons, And two more Image Assets. All of these .xcassets are given appropriate Target Membership (Properly added to Copy Bundle Resources of their own target. All of these .xcassets files have different names).

[image: Target Membership 1]

[image: Target Membership 2]

When deploying these apps on iPhone 5S, the AppIcon does not appear. I searched on google and came across this answer [Missing CFBundleIconName in Xcode9 iOS11 app release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46309698/4361652). I made changes like removing CFBundleIcons and adding CFBundleIconName in my Info.plist file. But nothing seems to work.

I have also assigned AppStore iOS 1024x1024 in AppIcon for all .xcassets file.

I created ipa for AdHoc distribution and verified that appropriate AppIcon gets bundled in the archive (By extracting ipa and browsing through Payload). While distributing ipa with [http://www.diawi.com](https://www.diawi.com/) the AppIcon is displayed on the device while the app is being installed (while circular progress is being shown on AppIcon on iPhone). But as the installation finishes, the AppIcon disappears.

[image: AppIcon displayed while installing. Disappears after install finishes.]

I checked the same AdHoc build on iPhone 5 (iOS 10.x.x) and the AppIcon is displayed on it. So, what exactly is creating problem for iOS 11 on iPhone 5S.

Xcode shows AppIcon for each target and their scheme as : [image: AppIcon applied for Target & their Scheme]

My Xcode version is : Version 9.0 (9A235).Someone please confirm that I have latest stable release (not beta / GM seed).

My iPhone 5S is updated on iOS 11 via official release (I haven't installed beta of iOS 11).

Comment: Facing the same issue

Comment: @genaks are you using pods?

Comment: Yes I am @Yahya Ibrahim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem with [cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6159). The shell-script located at 'Pods -> Target Support Files -> Pods-ProjectName -> Pods-ProjectName-resources.sh' contains a section (probably last) where it combines all asset catalogs into one, thus my exported archive would have assets from all the targets and results in unexpected AppIcon.

All I had to do was to remove the section in the shell script where asset catalogs were combined into one. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28717276/4361652) answer if you are experiencing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Open your app icons in Preview. Go to Tools -> Assign Profile. Select sRGB IEC61966-2.1 from the dropdown. You will have to do this for all the app icons you are using for your app.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Go to 'TARGETS -> Build Settings' and set your icon name in 'Asset Catalog App Icon Set Name'.